# savon soap attributes

Tags: soap, savon, netsuite

Am trying to query netsuite api for currencies. The following soap request works for me in SOAP UI client. But i am having a hard time trying to get the same working with ruby's savon gem version 0.9.7.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:messages_2012_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:core_2012_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:passport>
         <urn1:email>xxx@abc.com</urn1:email>
         <urn1:password>xxx</urn1:password>
         <urn1:account>xxx</urn1:account>
      </urn:passport>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:getAll>
         <urn:record recordType="currency"/>
      </urn:getAll>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Basically i am not able to set the attribute on the urn:record element. The following is not  working:

```
response = client.request :urn, :get_all do
  soap.body = { "urn:record" => { :attributes! => { "recordType" => "currency" } } }
end
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained on http://savonrb.com the key in the `attributes!` hash has to match the XML tag. You want to write something like this:

```
response = client.request :urn, :get_all do
  soap.body = {'urn:record'=>'',
               :attributes!=>{'urn:record'=>{'recordType'=>'currency'}}
              }
end
```

Please let us know whether this solves it for you.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, it seems to have gotten forward. But its now failing because i think its expecting "soapenv:" as a prefix for the Header and Body tags instead of just "env:". Do you know how to get that prefix going?

Comment: Got it, its `soap.env_namespace = "soapenv"` But that did not help as its not sending the soap header.

Comment: Worked finally with `soap.header = passport_header` setting. Where passport_header is   {
    'urn:passport' => {
      'urn:email' => NETSUITE_EMAIL,
      'urn:password' => NETSUITE_PWD,
      'urn:account' => NETSUITE_ACCT
    }
  }

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the raw soap request.  :get_all may need to be "getAll" to have savon take you literally; it may be changing it to `GetAll`

Comment: the default is that Savon converts `:get_all` into `getAll`. Please see documentation on http://savonrb.com

Answer (score 0):

In new versioin of savon you can place :attributes in the local context for the operation tag:

```
@interaction_client.call(:retrieve_interaction, message: message_hash, :attributes => {  'attachmentInfo' => include_attachments.to_s  })
```

In this case, the `attachmentInfo` attribute will be placed into the main operation tag linked with operation, in this example this would be the `ns:RetrieveInteractionRequest` tag.

Please note that the syntax does not contains the exclamation mark.